# Select TOP columns from table1, join table2 with their names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a TABLE1 with these two columns, storing departure and arrival identifiers from flights:

```
dep_id  arr_id

   1    2
   6    2
   6    2
   6    2
   6    2
   3    2
   3    2
   3    2
   3    4
   3    4
   3    6
   3    6
```

and a TABLE2 with the respective IDs containing their ICAO codes:

```
id  icao
1   LPPT
2   LPFR
3   LPMA
4   LPPR
5   LLGB
6   LEPA
7   LEMD
```

How can i select the top count of TABLE1 (most used departure id and most used arrival id) and group it with the respective ICAO code from TABLE2, so i can get from the provided example data:

```
most_arrivals   most_departures
    LPFR             LPMA
```

It's simple to get ONE of them, but mixing two or more columns doesn't seem to work for me no matter what i try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
select
    (select name
        from table2 where id = (
        select top 1 arr_id
        from table1
        group by arr_id
        order by count(*) desc)
    )  as most_arrivals,
    (select name
        from table2 where id = (
        select top 1 dep_id
        from table1
        group by dep_id
        order by count(*) desc)
    ) as most_departures
```

Comment: Wow, thank you Lashane. It works perfectly. So, this is basically a select grouping two independent selects for each column. So easy once you've seen it... Thanks again!

Comment: @NunoPinto yep, as soon as both selects return zero or one row - you can use them in this way

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

Create and populate tables.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Icao
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    icao nchar(4) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Flight
(
    dep_id int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Icao(id),
    arr_id int NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Icao(id)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Icao (id, icao)
    VALUES
    (1, N'LPPT'),
    (2, N'LPFR'),
    (3, N'LPMA'),
    (4, N'LPPR'),
    (5, N'LLGB'),
    (6, N'LEPA'),
    (7, N'LEMD');

INSERT INTO dbo.Flight (dep_id, arr_id)
    VALUES
    (1, 2),
    (6, 2),
    (6, 2),
    (6, 2),
    (6, 2),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 4),
    (3, 4),
    (3, 6),
    (3, 6);
```

Then do a SELECT using two subqueries.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 I.icao
        FROM dbo.Flight AS F
            INNER JOIN dbo.Icao AS I
                ON I.id = F.arr_id
        GROUP BY I.icao
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS 'most_arrivals',
    (SELECT TOP 1 I.icao
        FROM dbo.Flight AS F
            INNER JOIN dbo.Icao AS I
                ON I.id = F.dep_id
        GROUP BY I.icao
        ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS 'most_departures';
```

[image]

Click this button on the toolbar to include the actual execution plan, when you execute the query.

[image]

And this is the graphical execution plan for the query. Each icon represents an operation that will be performed by the SQL Server engine. The arrows represent data flows. The direction of flow is from right to left, so the result is the leftmost icon.

[image]

Comment: I suppose a JOIN is faster than another SELECT?

Comment: Unlikely. The SQL Server Query Optimizer determines the execution plan. It's a very smart piece of software and generally chooses the most efficient way to execute any particular query. You can view the graphical execution plan in SSMS by clicking a button on the toolbar.

Comment: In reality, there's little difference between the two answers you've got. I was part-way through writing mine, so I decided to post it anyway.

Comment: If you're interested, try both queries and examine the execution plans. You'll find it very instructive. It's quite likely the execution plans will be identical.

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been very helpful!